# Report Viewer error occurring occasionally

Tags: vb.net, report

My problem is about report viewer, I didn't know what is the cause of this problem. And it is only occurring occasionally. The problem says something like

`Local Report Processing`

`-----------------------------------`

`...The process access the file path path\expresion_host_5bc339f79dc24f2fb4b34667e9fadb13.dll`
`because it is being used by another process`

(sorry for not providing complete details, or image, they just chat me this)

but it didn't run, after close the form, i dispose the reportviewer and form, and if re-open it and do it many times, this error will show. And i'm freaking here to solve this, i tried to google it first but none of them help me with this.

by the way, in my workspace, this error is not showing. 
but in my boss, this error is showing, maybe because he is using Windows 8.

Comment: ReportViewer creates temporary assemblies when runs a report file that contains expressions: probably an antivirus is locking this temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Application Run As Administrator
2.) When you Close Application at that time use Application.exit at end of code

Answer (score 0):

When a report ( printing ) function is run, a dll ( it is a working temp file generated by  application to set a parameter etc.. )  is created in a temp folder for a millisecond and deleted.
At that time if the new antivirus program is catch the file, it also checks and release. and it is locked while it is being checked and your application dump ( the error message ) at that time.

So remove your anti virus you will see problem will be solved. Stopping anti virus may not enough. AV services continue to check every file and blockes.